How to validate related id existence with Pydantic?
In FastAPI + SqlAlchemy + Pydantic (v2) application how do you validate cases f.e. when you need to validate if related model with supplied from frontend id exists in database?
I tried to combine this type of validation with default FastAPI/Pydantic validation (validation of min_lenght, types, etc) but failed because I could not figure out how to pass session from get_session dependency into validation method validate_topic_id:
import typing
from typing import Any

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator, Field, ConfigDict
from pydantic_async_validation import ValidationInfo
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_async_engine("sqlite+aiosqlite:///:memory:")
SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()


class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = "questions"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    text: Mapped[str]
    topic_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("topics.id"))
    # here can be a lot of relations!!!
    topic: Mapped["Topic"] = relationship(back_populates="questions")


class Topic(Base):
    __tablename__ = "topics"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    text: Mapped[str]
    questions: Mapped[list["Question"]] = relationship(back_populates="topic")


async def get_session():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        await db.close()


class CreateQuestionDataSchema(BaseModel):
    text: str
    topic: Topic = Field(alias="topic_id", gt=0)

    @field_validator("topic", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_topic_id(cls, topic_id: int, info: ValidationInfo):
        session = info.context.get("session")  # how to put session in here? 
        stmt = select(Topic).where(Topic.id == topic_id)
        topic = await session.scalar(stmt)  # this I plan to execute in asyncio loop.run_until_complete
        if not topic:
            raise ValueError("Topic does not exist")
        return "topic"


class CreateTopicDataSchema(BaseModel):
    text: str


async def create_db_and_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    await create_db_and_tables()


@app.post("/topics")
async def create_topic(text: str = Body(embed=True), session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    topic = Topic(text=text)
    session.add(topic)
    await session.commit()
    return topic


@app.post("/things")
async def create_question(data: CreateQuestionDataSchema, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    question = Question(text=data.text, topic=data.topic)
    session.add(question)
    await session.commit()
    return question


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, reload=True)

The problem is in here:
class CreateQuestionDataSchema(BaseModel):
    text: str
    topic: Topic = Field(alias="topic_id", gt=0)

    @field_validator("topic", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate_topic_id(cls, topic_id: int, info: ValidationInfo):
        session = info.context.get("session")  # how to put session in here? 
        stmt = select(Topic).where(Topic.id == topic_id)
        topic = await session.scalar(stmt)  # this I plan to execute in asyncio loop.run_until_complete
        if not topic:
            raise ValueError("Topic does not exist")
        return topic

Now I'm thinking about separate validation class where fields are defined declaratively like in Django REST Framework.
But it would be cool to inject this type of validation into default validation with Pydantic because it returns errors and their location.
Please share your thoughts and experience.
P.S. There can be a lot of relations!!! Please don't offer insert data to validate whether relation exists or not.
P.P.S. I'll repeat it just in case. I need to inject relation existence validation into standard Pydantic validation mechanism to reuse how it returns errors and their location.

The general advice is to let Pydantic handle the data types/structure, but anything context related, such as if the topic ID exists, is handled in your API route. In this case, this is the type of validation an SQL database will do natively for you, so my advice would be to try to insert the record, and catch the error (I think SQLAlchemy will raise an IntegrityError, but don't quote me on that) and return a 4xx status code.

@M.O., the problem with what you advise is that there can be multiple relations and for frontend I need to return in which fields there are errors.

In that case, I'd write a separate function that takes the pydantic model, runs the necessary database queries, and then returns any errors. The principle still stands that the pydantic model validates the data "by itself", and any external validation happens separately.

Sorry I don't understand how to code external validations so that Pydantic handles errors location

If you only want to handle "the related object exists", you can do that by having a foreign key relationship - depending on your database and settings, that should generate an error when you try to insert the row in the database (and the database is the best candidate to know if something exists or not). If you want to apply additional business rules (the related object is owned by the same user, for example), you can do that in a service layer, where you validate the rules before adding the object to the session. Let pydantic worry about data validation, let your service validate rules.

There can be a lot of relations
